# Yii2 validation rule specific to a scenarios

Tags: yii2

I have the following rules and scenarios

```
public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name','email','password'],'required'],
            ['email','myvalidation'],
            ['email','email'],
            [['name', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'register'],
            ];
    }




public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['login'] = ['name','password','email'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

I want the `rule` `'myvalidation'` applied only to the `login` scenario and not at all in other cases.How this can be achieved in `Yii2` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just specify [on](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$on-detail) property in this validation rule:

```
['email', 'myvalidation', 'on' => 'login'],
```

Answer (score 16):

Remember you can also use "except". In example:

```
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['first_name', 'email', 'phone', 'password'], 'required', 'except' => 'changepassword'],
                [['password'], 'required', 'on' => 'changepassword']
]}
```

Comment: what is changepassword there ?

Comment: It is an scenario. That rule only applies if you set that scenario :)